# FeinCMS Initial Installation: Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, feincms

So I am trying to get FeinCMS up and running and I have it working on the backend but I cannot get a page to load:

this is how my models.py is setup:

```
Page.register_templates({
    'title': _('Standard template'),
    'path': 'base.html',
    'regions': (
        ('main', _('Main content area')),
        ('sidebar', _('Sidebar'), 'inherited'),
        ),
    })

Page.create_content_type(RichTextContent)
Page.create_content_type(MediaFileContent, TYPE_CHOICES=(
    ('default', _('default')),
    ('lightbox', _('lightbox')),
    ))
```

The error I get is

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /test/

zipfel/base.html

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/zipfel/base.html (File does not exist)
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/zipfel/base.html (File does not exist)
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/templates/zipfel/base.html (File does not exist)
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/feincms/templates/zipfel/base.html (File does not exist)
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mptt/templates/zipfel/base.html (File does not exist)
```

Now I understand that if I put a base.html file in either of those directories it should work.

2 questions:

What does the base.html contents need to be?
In order to be able to place the base.html in the app folder do I have to add that path to TEMPLATE_DIRS?

The FeinCMS installation has been rather tricky for me thus far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the absolute path to the TEMPLATE_DIRS and that allowed me to place the base.html where I wanted

in that file i placed the following code and I was able to view my page:

```
{% load feincms_tags %}

<div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% for content in feincms_page.content.main %}
        {{ content.render }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    {% for content in feincms_page.content.sidebar %}
        {{ content.render }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note, its not required to loop all content you could simply use the `feincms_render_region` tag. E.g. `{% feincms_render_region feincms_page "main" request %}{% endblock %}` where 'feincms_page' is the variable name for your page object.